# Inverse Bessel Process as strict local martingale without Ito's formula?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, harmonic-functions

Is there a way to prove that the inverse Bessel process $|B_t|^{-1}$ is a local martingale without using Ito's formula, considering that the Green's function

$$g(x)=\int_0^\infty p(t,x)dt=(2\pi^{d/2})^{-1} \Gamma(d/2-1)|x|^{2-d}$$

(with $p(t,x)$ as transition density of the three dimensional Brownian motion) is harmonic?

($|\cdot|$ should be the Euclidean norm.)